# Resolving 'Get-AzFunction' Cmdlet Recognition Issue

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

Requirement

This script connects to an Azure account, retrieves a list of functions in a specified Azure Function App, and determines the status (enabled or disabled) of each function endpoint. It then displays their status and health, iterating through the functions and providing details like function name, status, and health in the console output.

Exception

Get-AzFunction : The term 'Get-AzFunction' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.

this line of code

```
$functionStatus = (Get-AzFunctionApp -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $functionAppName | Get-AzFunction -Name $functionNameWithoutPrefix).State
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because their is no Command called Get-AzFunction.

> Requirement
> This script connects to an Azure account, retrieves a list of functions in a specified Azure Function App, and determines the status

To achieve this use the below script:

```
Connect-AzAccount -subscriptionid "b83"
 $functionStatus = Get-AzFunctionApp -ResourceGroupName "bojj"
$functionStatus
$functionStatus | Select-Object Name, Status
```

[image]

**`Edit:`**

If you want to get different functions and if its disable or not use below script:

```
$rgname = "vrbojja"
$funcName = "rithv2"
Get-AzResource -ApiVersion "2022-03-01" -Name $funcName -ResourceGroupName $rgname -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/sites/functions/" -ExpandProperties | ConvertTo-Json
```

Here $rgname is resource group name and $funcName is function app name.

**`Output:`**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ritwik, but my requirement is different. I want to see how many end points are there in a given function app and their status.

Comment: Endpoint means Functions inside Function app?

Comment: Edited my answer @RameshSB, check it once under edit section.